# Как задать последнему активному элементу класс?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Собственно нужно последнему классу active давать дополнительные класс opacity, но что-то идёт не так

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:false,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    },
})

var sbAllItms = $('.owl-item.active').length;
$('.owl-carousel .owl-item.active').eq(sbAllItms - 1).addClass('opacity');

owl.on('changed.owl.carousel',function(event) {
    sbAllItms = $('.owl-item.active').length;
    $('.owl-carousel .owl-item.active').removeClass('opacity');
  $('.owl-carousel .owl-item.active').eq(sbAllItms - 1).addClass('opacity');
})
```

```css
h4 {color: green; background:red;}

.opacity {
  opacity: .6;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Всё несколько проще `$('.owl-carousel .owl-item.active:last').addClass('opacity');`

Comment: @Pyramidhead, не совсем - https://jsfiddle.net/bjnz4y8e/68/

Comment: `нужно последнему классу active давать дополнительные класс opacity` - Приведённый мной фрагмент делает именно это. Быть может поясните, что именно вы хотите?

Comment: @Pyramidhead, так вы попробуйте карусель пролестните влево-вправо, ваш класс остается у предпоследнего элемента

Comment: Потому, что элемент с классом `active` в owl-carousel всегда один. Я показал, как `последнему классу active давать дополнительные класс opacity`. Получается, что вам нужно совсем не это. Тогда что?

Comment: @Pyramidhead, как это один? Всем видимым элементам дается класс active, если консоль не врет конечно, вот из видимых последнему мне и нужен класс opacity, причем всегда, независимо листаю я или нет

Comment: Класс `active` всегда только у одного элемента. У того, что видим в данный момент. Можете открыть консоль в вашем же примере на jsfiddle и убедиться в этом.

Comment: @Pyramidhead, может я неправильно вас понимаю, но вот же http://prntscr.com/ivgv0l

Comment: В вашем случае консоль врёт. Можете проверить иначе, добавив такие css правила `.owl-item {background: green;} .owl-item.active {background: red;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Последний элемент в наборе можно выбрать по индексу (-1), также выбрано не то событие слайдера.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  },
  onInitialized:slideOpacity,
  onTranslated:slideOpacity
})

function slideOpacity(){
  $('.owl-carousel .owl-item.opacity').removeClass('opacity');
  $('.owl-carousel .owl-item.active').eq(-1).addClass('opacity');
}
```

```css
h4 {
  color: green;
  background: red;
}
.owl-item{
  transition:all .3s ease;
}
.opacity {
  opacity: .6;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>7</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>8</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>9</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>10</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>11</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>12</h4>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```